# Drip campaign help in automation studio

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio

I have already set up a campaign in automation studio exacttarget where data is pulled form the SFTP and filtered into the language category and a welcome email is sent to the customers who are filtered in English or French.

The automation will be running daily and only new people who are added are sent the welcome email with the sent date filter settings.

The part I need some advise is this same people I want to send them a "Second Email" after a 30 day period.

As mentioned I am still new to this, do I just add a "30 day wait period" step and Send new email step? Or do I create a separate automation for this?

Thing is the automation will be running daily so I wondering will the 30 day wait period will like cause any issue like not allowing the automation to add new people the next day as there is a 30 day wait period?

Apologies if I confuse anyone reading this but any advise or help will be greatly appreciated :)

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

I personally always keep these separate so it does affect each other if you want to make any changes or if you want to send it on a different day/time.

If you have a system generated date (use current date if field is empty) or if you have a date field in the data that you could use, you could do it two ways below

1. Create a filter that’s based on your date being 30 days ago and use this in your user initiated email send. This filter would get built when the send happens.

Or

2. If you know how to write sql you could write a script to write it to a new data extension and use that in the user initiated email send

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the tips. I tried experimenting and ran into a road block.

I created a simple automation where
Email 1 - is send to Customer 1 on 30th Dec and customer 2 on 31st Dec. As you can send from the screenshot of my masterlist :)
[image]

For Email 2 I wanted to send to those who were added 2 days ago so created a filter from the master list as this.

[image]

I kinda got confused here and thought the DATE_SENT is after Today - 2days would pick Dec 30 but it picked both Dec 30 and 31 after I ran the interaction filter. So I am not too sure what i did wrong with my data filter steps :(